# How set doctype html in JS or React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, canvas, doctype

I made canvas with the height of window.innerHeight, and for some reason it has 100% screen height + 4 pixels out of somewhere, I found a solution that I need to declare doctype html, but don't know how to do in react, where everything is written in JavaScript.
Any suggestions?

Edit: declaring doctype, 4 additional pixels doesn't go away, any ideas how to get rid of it?

Comment: Find your index.html and set it there. It all depends on what you use to write your react. Also modern browsers will assume the correct doctype these days

Comment: oh yeah indeed, forgot about public folder, haven't coded for awhile, gotta remember simple things over again, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add it to your `index.html` file (which would be the html file where you mount your react app root div)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has this problem, there's few possible reasons:

- Doctype html isn't declared
- Canvas has to be displayed as block

Answer (score 0):

It passed time and, probably, it's an hard way response but... could be help for someone. So...

1. The *"100% screen height + 4 pixels"* is, probably, a css role problem, not of doctype html (it declare only the roles of html applied)
2. Applied it in direct plain js after dom load not have sense (for SEO and for browser... it's too late)
3. Addeding a doctype can be a not simple action if you aren't an expert of node and react dev beacause foresee understood it in their base (so, *"make a custom ecosystem in react for node"*)... If you can and you are in node, for add a doctype, one of way is a simple custom response before release the page from an ssr template (so, a middleware). An exemple:

   ```
   const React = require('react')
   const ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server')
   const MyHtmlTemplate= require('./mytemplate.jsx')

   const ssrTemplate = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<MyHtmlTemplate {...{props}}/>)

   module.exports = function MiddlewareForSSR ( req, res ) {
       res.send( '<!DOCTYPE html>'+yourssrTemplate )
   }
   ```

   You not need to reapply it after hydrate in clientside, so... you have it in plain Js ready for your document

---

Documentation:

- [NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/en/about)
- [Express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

  - [Express > Middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)
- [React](https://react.dev/)

  - [React > Server Side Render](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/server/renderToString)
  - [React > Client Side Hydrate](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/client/hydrateRoot)